# React Vite clear Cache on client side

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have a react application deployed to AWS Amplify. However, every time I push a new feature to the pipeline, the feature will not appear on the live site right away. I understand that the build takes time but the problem persists even after Amplify notifies me that the build was completed. I believe it has to do with the browser cache, because opening up the site in an incognito tab works.

Therefore, does anyone know how to address the issue? I could not ask clients to clear their cache every time I made an update...

Answer (score 3):

You can add `Cache-Control` tag on your `public/index.html`

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Example.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've got the same issue as OP, but this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can also disable your broswer caches by inspect then go to your network tab and disable your caches then run `npm run dev`  with flag `--force` to rebuild dependencies again and refresh your broswer

more info can be found here in vite doc website https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#browser-cache

Comment: This didn't work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: How would this solve the problem when experienced by other users other than the developer?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issues with my build deployments before.
What I did was to create a CacheBuster file that compares the app version on every client-side page load and automatically deletes caches when an older version is found.
you can see a tutorial here: https://dev.to/flexdinesh/cache-busting-a-react-app-22lk

But you'll have to modify the code to work in VITE environment and however you want to customize it for your project.

for VITE React use vite-plugin-version package to automatically generate your version.json file