# Firebase Hosting and React Lazy Loading Issue: Unable to Access Specific JS Chunk Versions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

***Context***: I'm encountering a significant issue with Firebase Hosting and React, specifically related to lazy-loaded chunks. After deploying a new version, users trying to access specific JS chunks (e.g., checkout.2.js) are being redirected to my React Router instead of fetching the requested JS version. This behaviour poses a challenge, especially with lazy-loaded React components.

***Senario:***

- Using client-side lazy loading of React components.
- Firebase Hosting with a domain like eg.web.app.
- Lazy-loaded checkout page with chunk names like checkout.[hash].js.

I'm using client side lazy loading of react and firebase hosting.

For example Let's say I've lazy loaded checkout page and my chunck name is checkout.[hash].js and my firebase domain is eg.web.app. They can visit this checkout chunk like eg.web.app/asserts/checkout.[hash].js

I've deploying v1 and checkout chunk looks like this checkout.1.js and some users are browsing catalogue page. Meanwhile there is an update and the checkout chunk is chekcout.2.js.

Now when the user click on checkout button they expect to see checkout.1.js. However, it downloads my main index.html page as its configured as SPA.

***Expected Result***:

Irrespective of deployment version I would like to access both version of checkout asserts like xyz.web.app/assets/checkout.1.js or xyz.web.app/assets/checkout.2.js

***Steps to reprduce*** :

- Deploy two version.
- Open the JS chunck in new tab.
- Rollback to old version of firebase.
- Wait for rollback.
- Force refresh the old JS chunck it would load the index.html

Here is my firebase.json

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/assets/**",
        "destination": "/assets/**"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5002
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 4001
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you think Firebase Hosting (or any web service) can do in this situation?  Your code is asking to fetch a file from the web service that no longer exists on the web service.

One thing you could consider in YOUR code, is to have some type of periodic check for a `version file` on the server that changes with each new version of your app's build.  Your React app periodically checks that the "version file" it was compiled/deployed with is there and if not, your code forces a refresh of the entire app thereby loading the newly deployed version of the app.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. I solved it this way. Now I'm pushing all the chunks to cloud storage and I'm just updating the index.html. In case of a revert, I would redeploy the old codebase.

Comment: [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75658883/229326) seems to offer answers to your situation.